# Selecting rows in R with "Yes" in one column of a set of columns, and NOT "Yes" in all columns of another set of columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains only yes/no strings and NAs. something similar to this:

```
    X1   X2   X3   Y1   Y2  Y3   Z1   Z2   Z3
1  <NA>   no  yes <NA>  yes  no <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  <NA>  yes   no  yes <NA> yes  yes <NA>  yes
3   yes  yes <NA>  yes  yes yes <NA> <NA>  yes
4   yes <NA>   no <NA>  yes  no <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  <NA>   no  yes <NA>  yes  no  yes   no <NA>
6  <NA> <NA>   no <NA>  yes  no <NA> <NA> <NA>
7    no   no  yes   no   no yes  yes   no <NA>
8   yes  yes   no   no   no yes   no   no   no
9   yes <NA>  yes <NA>  yes  no  yes  yes  yes
10   no   no <NA>  yes   no  no  yes  yes   no
```

I want to know how I can find out how many rows include a "yes" at ANY '3' var (X3/Y3/Z3', and a "no"/na at ALL '1/2' vars (X1/X2/Y1/Y2 etc.) in the df.

Sample set created with the following:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  X1 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  X2 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  X3 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Y1 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Y2 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Y3 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Z1 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Z2 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
  Z3 = sample(c("yes", "no", NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: `table` command would be helpful

Comment: @Heroka The user is obviously new here and doesn't understand how to ask questions with replicable examples and etc. Whoever downvoted this question please un-do it. It's a pretty challenging question , our new user here just needs to learn how to ask it more appropriately

Comment: @road_to_quantdom I didn't downvote the Q, but being new is not an excuse for not properly asking questions. Posting screenshots of data is not the way to go.

Comment: @road_to_quantdom The purpose of DV and CV is to encourage the OP to improve his question. Without it, they will have no motivation to do so. While this question will remain not useful to no one as it lacks a reproducible example, desired output and clear statement of the problem. It also doesn't show any research effort. Thus, it is fully qualified for a DV/CV until further notice.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers folks, best to go in at the deep end. If I'm still not getting it, please be as brutal as necessary...

Comment: Or you could just read the help Center and follow the rules to start with. You still haven't posted any code which makes this question a code request at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you have the dataframe organized the way you do now i.e., comp1type1,comp1type2,comp1type3,comp2type1,...,comp[I]type[J]. I am sure you can use the following method.

```
    ncomp <- 20
    ntype <- 3
    vecone <- df[,seq(1,ncomp*ntype,ntype)]
    vectwo <- df[,seq(2,ncomp*ntype,ntype)]
    vecthree <- df[,seq(3,ncomp*ntype,ntype)]

    # now that we have the vectors of types seperated into data.frame's
    # it'll be easier to do what we want
    # this first condition will find which rows type1/2 have No or NA for all
    condition1 <- rowSums(vecone=="No" | is.na(vecone)) == ncol(vecone)
    condition2 <- rowSums(vectwo=="No" | is.na(vectwo)) == ncol(vectwo)
    # this third condition will find which rows type3 have atleast one Yes
    condition3 <- rowSums(vecthree =="Yes",na.rm=T) >= 1
```

Now you may use these conditions to figure out how many rows include a Yes for any type3 and a No/NA for all type1/2

```
sum(condition1 & condition2 & condition3)
```

Comment: thanks, this is really useful. One thing...when I try `condition1 <- rowSums(vecone=="No" || is.na(vecone)) == ncol(vecone)
condition2 <- rowSums(vectwo=="No" || is.na(vectwo)) == ncol(vectwo)` I'm getting an error like this: **Error in rowSums(vecone == "No" || is.na(vecone)) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions**. I tried using `as.matrix` but the condition then returned just a single `FALSE` instead of a logi value for each row.

Comment: try using `|` instead of `||`